# Communication between browser and java component

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, web

I am currently working on a point of sale application. 
we have a existing system based on java which uses javapos to integrate with the devices (such as receipt printer, cash drawer , MSR etc).
now we are trying to port the java based thick client to service enable , so it is set to become a web app backed by html5 and spring webservice

my problem is to integrate the devices to the web ie browser so that the cashier can access the point of sale application from the browser  .

how do i integrate the devices to the web app now. one option i have is deploying a java component in the register and make it communicate it to browser via websocket.

browser<-> websocket <-> java device component in local system

Is there any better way to do this? i need the technology which enable me to do the same.

i have considered the applet as well but the problem is the local java component  is kinda huge and it will have different device drivers for each system.

Comment: Did I understand this correct: Yu have a) A Server running Java-WebAPP with a http-API, b) the html client running in an browser and c) Devices conneted to the Computer, where the Browser is running?

Comment: a webapp in remote , html rendered in browser where the devices are connected. @ChristianKuetbach

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX offers a pretty decent web browser component, that allows easy communication between the Javascript code that runs in the page and the Java code outside. You could port your application so that:

1. It uses JavaFX, openning a window with just a browser component and pointing it to your web application
2. Implement the web app as normal - it will display in the browser component
3. Move the device-specific Java code in the JavaFX app, expose its methods to the browser; now the Javascript code will call Java and (hopefully) you will be able to reuse most of your existing code, excluding UI code of course

A "Hybrid" JavaFX/HTML application example is [iBreed](https://github.com/in-sideFX/iBreed) (it is a framework that you can use actually).

Comment: my team have decided to go with html after a POC with javafx, is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make it work, but you will need one more piece of software.

1. Webserver (hosting the HTML-files and API)
2. Client PC (runnning the HTML-frontend in a browser) woth conected devices
3. **new** service running on the client PC, with a Web-API for the connected devices

I think, this is exactly the same approach as you mentioned with websockets. (Ony for older browser).

Take a look at atmosphere. This may help you to get the websocket stuff done:
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere